# What did Rand ask the Aelfinn?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

What three questions did Rand al’Thor ask when he went through the twisted redstone doorframe in the Stone of Tear, and what were the answers he got?

Comment: The third question will apparently be revealed in the forthcoming (print) encyclopaedia. ([Source](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=873#4))

Answer (score 15):

1. Q: “How can I win the Last Battle and survive?”
   A: “The east and north must be as one. The west and south must be as one.
     The two must be as one. To live you must die.”

   ([Word of Demigod](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod) says
   [this counts as one question](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=641#2).)
2. Q: Wording unknown, but something along the lines of
     “How can I remove the Dark One’s taint from *saidin*?”
   A: The answer was difficult to understand,
     and the exact wording is not known, except that:

   - Herid Fel said it stated
     “sound principles, in both high philosophy and natural philosophy,”
     and
   - Rand eventually unriddled the answer and got the job done.
3. According to [Brandon Sanderson’s Wheel of Time Answers From #TorChat](http://www.tor.com/blogs/2013/01/brandon-sandersons-wheel-of-time-answers-from-torchat),

   > Rand’s third question to the Aelfinn involved Rand asking how to kill the Dark One.
   >   More detail on these will most likely be put in the Encyclopedia.

   But note that,

   > in AMoL, Rand realizes that this is actually the wrong question to have asked.

Comment: "The third question and its answer are not known" .... yet.

Comment: I have heard indications that the 3rd question may be one of the things Brandon might never reveal. Either way, I'll update the answer when we learn more.

Comment: Actually, I've just been browsing [wotfaq](http://wotfaq.dragonmount.com/node/167) and it seems the 3rd question was whether or not he should go back to the Two Rivers to face Fain.

Comment: Hmmm, but the [Encyclopedia](http://encyclopaedia-wot.org/prophecies/aelfinn.html) backs up your answer. Which is correct?

Comment: Note that WoTFAQ is out of date here; there’s no mention of the fact that Rand asked how to win the Last Battle or the “… must be as one” part of the answer. My gut feeling is that the FAQ is less reliable here, but I’m quite willing to be corrected & to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: There might be some confusion. Mat certainly asked whether he should go back home to the Two Rivers and was told to go to Rhuidean instead. Maybe the author of the FAQ was mistaken?

Comment: There is a hint to the third question in AMoL, when Rand realizes he’d asked the wrong question.