# Why did Moiraine know for certain Thom was not dead?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

I'm rereading (or rather, listening to audiobook versions of) the Wheel of Time series.

When Thom told Rand and Mat to run away from the Fade in Whitebridge, Rand was certain Thom would be dead. Under normal circumstances, I would agree, since Fades aren't exactly merciful, pacifist creatures.

However, Moiraine was 100% sure Thom was still alive, despite Rand's insistence. I know Moiraine and Thom would later bond and get married. Did Moiraine have a reading from Min to be sure of that? Or did she learn or deduce that knowledge elsewhere?

Comment: Probably from the Aelfinn: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30543/what-were-the-questions-and-answers-the-aelfinn-gave-to-moiraine

Comment: @muru this was before she ever met the aelfinn.

Comment: Because Thom is awesome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

She knows from Min's predictions, as DavidH says in [the related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30543/what-were-the-questions-and-answers-the-aelfinn-gave-to-moiraine) linked to in the comments:

> Moiraine knew Thom would survive Tanchico because Min told her they would marry in The Eye of the World in Baerlon. This is also how she knew he had survived the fade in White Bridge.

I'll see if I can dig up the exact quote from the book.

> "Min? She saw something about Thom?" "She saw a great deal," Moiraine said wryly. "About all of you. I wish I could understand half of what she saw, but even she does not. Old barriers fail. But whether what Min does is old or new, she sees true. Your fates are bound together. Thom Merrilin's, too."
>   WoT-EoTW chapter 45

Comment: The quote you provide isn't proof that Min said Thom would marry Moiraine, but she did see a lot of things that hadn't come to pass by the time of tEotW.

Comment: There's never any explicit proof, but lots of hints. Moiraine tells the super girls that she reckons she knows her future husband better than they know theirs, then she quickly sidesteps any questions about it.

Comment: @randal'thor Update: I just read Moiraine's entry in the recently published encyclopedia, and it does explicitly confirm that Min told her about her future marriage to Thom. So one minor mystery solved :)